# Can't make COPY from remote host to Redshift work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a gzipped file on a local machine and want to load it to Redshift.
My command looks like this:

```
\COPY tablename FROM 's3://redshift.manifests/copy_from_yb01_urlinfo.txt' REGION 'us-east-1' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=...;aws_secret_access_key=...' SSH GZIP;
```

But I get a message "s3:/redshift.manifests/copy_from_yb01_urlinfo.txt: No such file or directory".

But this file even public: https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift.manifests/copy_from_yb01_urlinfo.txt.
Moreover, the user whose credentials I use have a full access to S3 and Redshift: http://c2n.me/iEnI5l.png

And even more weird is the fact that I could perfectly access that file with **same credentials** from AWS CLI:

```
> aws s3 ls redshift.manifests
2014-08-01 19:32:13        137 copy_from_yb01_urlinfo.txt
```

How to diagnose that further?

Just in case, I connect to my Redshift cluster via psql (PostgreSQL cli):

```
PAGER=more LANG=C psql -h ....us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -U ... -d ...
```

**edit:**

Uploaded file to S3 - same error on COPY...
And again I uploaded it and ran COPY with same credentials.

```
\COPY url_info FROM 's3://redshift-datafiles/url_info_1.copy.gz' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=...;aws_secret_access_key=...' GZIP;
```

I am going to despair...

Comment: From the error message it looks like the S3 path is incorrect s3:/redshift.... instead of s3://redshift.... Can you confirm if that is not a typo ?

Comment: Yes, error message have only one forward slash. But in my command I have two, exactly as quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh.

The fix was to remove backslash in the beginning of the command.
Can't remember why I started writing it... Actually I already began writing it when I exported data from local PostgreSQL installation.

This is so stupid) One small rubber duck could have saved me a day or two.

Comment: Ah, I see - it was really needed in psql shell to perform copy under system user privileges, not SQL ones.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to copy to RedShift using a manifest file, you need to use the `MANIFEST` command at the end like :

```
\COPY tablename FROM 's3://redshift.manifests/copy_from_yb01_urlinfo.txt' REGION 'us-east-1' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=...;aws_secret_access_key=...' SSH GZIP MANIFEST;
```

Comment: AWS doc says otherwise: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/load-from-host-steps-run-copy.html. But nevertheless I have tried to add MANIFEST - error message is the same.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help btw!